# Many-To-One/ One-To-Many Relation column not showing up in find() and Update request not checking Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: typescript, entity, nestjs, typeorm

I have tried changing the name of the column.
Used the repository.find({select: ['id', 'name','ForeignRelation'],} ,but this throws error, that 3rd parameter is invalid.

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "./User";
@Entity()
export class Photo {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column()
url: string;

@ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.photos)
user: User;
}



import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany} from "typeorm";
import {Photo} from "./Photo";
@Entity()
export class User {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column()
name: string;

@OneToMany(type => Photo, photo => photo.user)
photos: Photo[];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the repository to include relations, you have to add a `relations` attribute to the repository's `find` method argument like this:

```js
const usersWithPhotos = await this.userRepository.find({relations: ['photos']});
```

Another way to do this without having to explicitly define the included relations when calling the repository's `find` method would be to make an eager relation this way:

```js
@Entity()
export class User {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(
    type => Photo,
    photo => photo.user,
    {eager: true}
  )
  photos: Photo[];
}
```

This will automatically include the `photos` relation when querying for users.